# Update list in a component when database has updated React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need some help to think here. I now get and displays a list of user from my database depending on if the user is set to true or false. 
And this works fine, but when i change a user from true to false in the database i would like to update the list that is displayed.

if i re render the page componetWillMount will do the job for me, but i would like to update the list without re render it.

I´ve looked and tried with componentWillUpdate but cant make it work.

```
 class activeUser extends Component {
// Call fetchList to get access to the users
 componentWillMount () {
this.props.fetchList()

   this.createDataSource(this.props)
}

 componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
// nextProps are the next set of props that this component
// will be rendered with
// this.props is still the old set of props

  this.createDataSource(nextProps)
}

createDataSource ({ users }) {
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
  })

  this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(users)
}

// Render out the users
renderRow (user) {
 return <ListUserItem user={user} />
}

render () {

  return (

    <View>

      <View style={{ height: 320, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 
'center', marginTop: 35 }} >

        <ListView
         showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
  />
    </View>
  </View>

  )
 }
}

 const mapStateToProps = state => {
 const users = _.map(state.list, (val) => {
  return {...val}
})
return { users }
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchList})(GoingOut)
```

Comment: You need to think about how does your react component know that your DB has been updated? ```ComponentWillUpdate``` will only fires if you pass new props to your component. The problem is your component currently only get's the data from your db once. This means if you want the component to update without the need to refresh you need to call your database every x seconds and fetch the data, check if the data is different from your current data and change your component state if the state is different.